# How to listen to webhooks from bash script?

Tags: git, bash, awk, netcat

I want to listen to webhook from *GitHub* and launch a bash script (`git pull`) on any new commit.

I don't want to use `python` or `nodejs` only bash script. 
Is it possible? I believe that `netcat` can do it.

I don't need to parse the request. Only listen to specific port, and if someone try to connect to that port, to run a script.

**Optional:** Maybe netcat can pipe the request body, to `awk` or `pgrep` and filter only to `post` request, or even extract the REPO name to an enviroment variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a while loop with netcat which is quite nasty:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    /the/script/you/want/to/run
done < <(netcat -l 8888 | grep '^POST ')
```

Disclaimer: Untested

Answer (score 0):

Socat?

http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html

Just throwing it out there,  I want to do the similar thing as Aminadav,  but don't necessarily need to use http webhook (I guess I could get voted down :)

If you go multicast you can control a cluster.  Who needs webhooks?

The first page of that tutorial shows you can receive a packet and fork a command like "git pull" for example,  which could then have a post-merge hook in it that ran more elaborate tasks on each cluster node as it did a pull.  Use git to distribute,  but don't poll the git server,  instead trigger a pull with the multicast socat.  Have yet to try this...